# Does Graphql-java support array of objects as query parameter for complex objects?

Tags: graphql-java

I am currently implementing graphql with java spring-boot. As a sample I have a schema like below:

```
type Book {
  id:ID
  name:String
  author:[Author]
  publisher:Publisher
}

type Author {
  authorId:ID
  authorName:String
}

type Publisher. {
  publisherId:ID
  publisherName:String
}
```

All of the above are fetched through independent rest apis underneath. I need to fetch an array of Books.

I can always have independent queries for each book:

```
eg:query {
  _678:bookbyId(id:678) {
  id
  name
  author {
    id
  }
  publisher {
    id
  }
  _679:bookbyId(id:679 ){
    id
    name
    author {
      id
    }
    publisher {
      id
    }
  }
```

But is there a better way to query like

```
bookbyId([id:678,id:679]){
  id
  name
  author {
    id
  }
  publisher {
    id
  }
```

If yes, how do I handle mapping of author and publisher to the right book?